# JSF sample project managed beans error, unable to print managed beans message to html

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I started to implement a very basic JSF application but i am unable to print the JSF Managed Beans message to html..

Here is my code :

HelloWorld.java :

```
package com.project.managedbeans;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="helloWorld", eager=true)
@RequestScoped
public class HelloWorld {

private String message;

public HelloWorld(){
    System.out.println("Hello World Managed Bean is created");
}

public String getMessage(){
    return "Hello World ! ";
}

public void setMessage(String message){
    this.message = message;
}
```

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<body>
#{helloWorld.message}

</body>
</html>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_1.xsd"
version="2.1">

</faces-config>
```

and web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"   xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-  app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
<display-name>jsfSampleProject</display-name>
<welcome-file-list>
 <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
 <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
 <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF   Specification 2.5.2</description>
 <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
 <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
 <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
 <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
 <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
</web-app>
```

and when i run the application on apache server, the page i see under

localhost:8080/jsfSampleProject/   is :

#{helloWorld.message}

I have JSF 2.1 Mojorra under Libraries tab. What do you think the problem is ?

Thanks.

Comment: what error are you getting? Are you using Netbeans?

Comment: i am using eclipse ide, i added the error to question, i get #{helloWorld.message} instead Hello World !

Comment: change to @SessionScope and let me know what you get.. (I know this is not a problem)

Comment: nope, nothing changed, i tried various things including @ApplicationScoped but nothing changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that welcome file list accepts **file names that are physically present** in your web app, and that is `index.xhtml`. **Note** that none of your welcome files match that condition.

Next, your file is **not handled by the `FacesServlet`**. That is, requested URL does not correspond to the servlet URL mapping in your web.xml. **Note** that your mapping `*.jsf` doesn't match your requested files as well.

All in all, the following excerpt from web.xml will solve your problem:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Of course, you'll need the file `index.xhtml` at the root of your web application.

Comment: i was dealing with this problem for 1 week. it take you 5 mins to solve. Thank you very much..